# PHP why preg_match result different from normal output?

Tags: php, preg-match, preg-match-all

This is first php code

```
$bbtext = "<br/><br/>This [color=red]is [b]bold[/b] and this is [u]underlined[/u] and [color=green]this [/color]is in [i]italics[/i] with[/color] a [color=red] red color[/color]";
preg_match_all('/\[color=(.*?)\]/', $bbtext, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
print_r($matches);
```

the above php code output is,
[Output 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gMByg.png)

Then, other php code

```
$pattern = '/abcd/';
$string = 'weruhfabcdwuir';
preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
print_r($matches);
```

output is,
[Output 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Xtmt.png)

In second php code, **abcd** is start from **6th** index position. *(we know that index always starts from 0).* It is working correctly on php output.

In first php code, **[color=red]** is start from **5th** index position. but, output is shown as 15.

why this difference occurred on **output 1**?

Comment: And `<br/><br/>` is what? Empty spaces?

Comment: thanks, i have not looked this <br/><br/>

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you think it starts at character offset 5, 15 looks right to me:

```
<br/><br/>This [color=red]is [b]bold[/b] and this is [u]underlined[/u] and [color=green]this [/color]is in [i]italics[/i] with[/color] a [color=red] red color[/color]";
               ^ character offset 15
```

Are we missing something?